# Binding to a sub-property

Tags: binding

I built a struct named Fraction, with three properties: *double Value*, *int Numerator* and *int Denominator*. In my data source I use the Fraction as a property, *Fraction Position*.

The data is bound like this:

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Position.Numerator}"/>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Position.Denominator}"/>
```

but the binding happens to work only one way - from source to target. I tried to catch the SourceUpdated event, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to force two-way binding? I tried *Mode=TwoWay*, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create `Position` as a dependency property so that when target updates source updates too

**Edit**

please check it should be something like

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Position", typeof(Fraction), typeof(NoteUserControl),new UIPropertyMetadata(new Fraction()));

public Fraction Position
        {
            get { return (Fraction)GetValue(PositionProperty ); }
            set 
            { 
                SetValue(PositionProperty, value); 

            }
        }
```

Hope **NoteUserControl** is the Class in which you have defined the dependency property

Comment: I added this line:
    
public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Position", typeof(Fraction), typeof(NoteUserControl)); 

and the binding stopped working at all!

Comment: I tried it, with UIPropertyMetadata and without it, but it still doesn't work. I hope that, as a musician, you'd like to see my project. Its a MIDI pianoroll. Please send hello to gideonrv@raveh.org.